# I want my variable value3 to be added with 5 for ten times using loop.But it only add for one time.How to solve this?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

Help me.I was going to add variable value3 with 5 when button rel is clicked for ten time using for loop

```
     int j;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
        rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (rel!=null) {
                        int i;
                        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(value);
                        value3 = value2 + 5.00;
                        balance.setText(String.valueOf(value3));}
                    }
```

Comment: Where is value defined? Why are you setting the on click listener 10 times as well? we need more code and information

Comment: What result do you get? Without knowing exactly what you want to do it looks wrong that you convert `value` each time in the loop since it is the same so maybe do it before the loop. It is also strange that you set a value for `balance` each time in the loop, shouldn't it be done once after the loop?

Comment: nor `value` neither `value2` is not being changed inside the loop... the result of `value2 + 5` will always be the same (actually `value2` is being set in the loop, but always to the same value)

Answer (score 1):

no for loops on top and:

```
rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rel!=null) {
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                    value3 += 5.00;
                }
                balance.setText(String.valueOf(value3));
           }
       } 
}
```